# How can I start a Svelte app with netlify-cli

Tags: svelte, netlify

I am trying to test my Svelte app locally (*npm run dev*) before deploying to Netlify

I can start a Svelte app locally by using the following code in *package.json*

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "sirv public --no-clear"
},
```

But if I want so start the netlify-cli server I need

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "netlify dev"
},
```

How can I square this circle?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is  non-question. You just use

```
netlify dev
```

and it works